# How to use MatSnackBar in global error handler with standalone components?

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I've created this error handler:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material/snack-bar";

Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    
})
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

    openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
        this._snackBar.open(message, action);
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
        console.error(error);
        this.openSnackBar('An error occurred: ' + error.message??"No message", 'Close');
    }

}
```

and configured my app in main.ts to use it as the ErrorHandler:

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


import { ApplicationConfig, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';  
import { MyErrorHandler } from './error-handling'; 

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),

    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: MyErrorHandler, 
    }
  ]
};
```

However, it gives error as it doesn't provide the "MatSnackBar" anywhere.
It works correctly if i remove all references to MatSnackBar and I just log the error to console or something like that.

I have tried importing it in the @Injectable() decorator, but that didn't change behaviour.

How to use MatSnackBar or other dependencies in my ErrorHandler since i'm using standalone components and so i don't have a Module where i can import the MatSnackBarModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using "deps" in the app.config.ts file:
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

```
{
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: MyErrorHandler,
      deps: [
        MatSnackBar
      ]
    }
```

**Important**: "deps" doesn't work if you put it in the @Injectable() decorator, only here in the providers array.